# cambiar el tamaño de un campo en sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy usando sql server management studio y al campo Price quiero modificarle el tamaño de 8 a 10
¿cómo podría hacerlo? de antemano gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tamaño definido no son caracteres. Son bytes.

```
Create table dbo.discounts(
itemId uniqueidentifier,
Quantity int,
Description nvarchar(30),
Price money
);
```

Después de haber creado la tabla, en Management Studio

[image: M1]

En la misma la documentación dice:

[image: M2]

En la documentación sobre [money](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[image: Money]

Y si inserto una fila.

```
INSERT INTO DBO.DISCOUNTS(itemId
                        , Quantity
                        , Description
                        , PRICE)
VALUES
       ( NewId(), 1, 'Fila1', 922337203685477.58 );

SELECT *
    , len(Price) as longitud
    , DATALENGTH(price) as ocupaBytes
       FROM dbo.discounts;
```

[image: Result]

Es posible que la información de las pantallas, al no disponer de la misma versión de Management Studio, sea un pelín diferente, pero en esencia, **Money** se ve en **bytes**